# Mysql group_concat(id) as ids in a left join and using ids to select all columns in id group

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have a table that contains some articles with it's own ID and shared SKU key.
I've tried to make the query with a left join and using group result to take all ids returned from the query.

My data structure is like that:

```
id -    name   - sku - ...
1  - felix     - cat
2  - tom       - cat - ...
3  - sylvester - cat - ...
4  - red       - pen - ...
5  - blue      - pen - ...
```

I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` 
[LEFT/RIGHT/INNER] JOIN 
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id) AS idsgroup FROM `test` WHERE (attribute_name = 'sku') GROUP BY value_name LIMIT 0, 3 
) bind
ON id IN (bind.idsgroup);
```

this query is wrong, it return only 1 id per group instead all ids selected from concat or in LEFT JOIN case, obviously all rows.

Any suggestion workaround to achieve the right result?

EDIT:

here a fiddle with the structure:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6747a

And the query i tried into:

```
   SELECT * FROM `view_test` 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT entity_id) AS idsgroup FROM `view_test` WHERE (attribute_name = 'sku') GROUP BY value_name LIMIT 0, 3 
    ) bind
    ON entity_id IN (bind.idsgroup);
```

As this pic show, my result lost some ids, part of the group.
[image: query result]

EDIT 2:
after i used FIND_IN_SET() suggested by Kickstart the result is the expected:

```
SELECT * FROM `view_test` 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT entity_id) AS idsgroup FROM `view_test` WHERE (attribute_name = 'sku') GROUP BY value_name LIMIT 0, 3 
) bind
ON FIND_IN_SET(entity_id, bind.idsgroup);
```

[image: Right result]

Comment: What's your desired result?

Comment: Using group by sku and limit group result, after take all rows contained in group concat and get all data. Then not only the first id under the group_concat, but all ids in the block.

For example, if i have 4 variants under the same sku, and 1000 or more sku, i whant to get the first 10 block of sku and then return all rows under the same sku not only one per sku.

Comment: He meant: give the expected output in the form you gave your "data structure", and with the data in that example. Although your query suggests that this is actually not your your data structure, but you have an attribute table. So add the correct table structure (if you have an attribute table, it's probably 2 tables), sample data and your desired output from that sample data, and maybe additional an sql fiddle or create/insert statements (although I think it is just a matter of what column you have to group by).

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT returns a string containing comma separated values, rather than returning a list of separate values Hence  IN will not work except when there is ONLY 1 id returned by the GROUP_CONCAT. You could use _ON FIND_IN_SET(id, bind.idsgroup)_ but it shouldn't be necessary (I suspect it just needs an extra level of self join). Post some real data and the output you want from that data and hopefully we can find a real solution.

Comment: I updated with a fiddle and a screen of the result.

Comment: Please update your question with "What Should Be In the Result"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple fix would appear to be to use FIND_IN_SET for the join. But this is a bit of a hack and will not be that quick.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `view_test` 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT entity_id) AS idsgroup 
    FROM `view_test` 
    WHERE (attribute_name = 'sku') 
    GROUP BY value_name 
    LIMIT 0, 3 
) bind
ON FIND_IN_SET(entity_id, bind.idsgroup);
```

Further not sure why you have a LIMIT on the sub query, especially without an order clause.

Possibly better to use a sub query to just get the DISTINCT entity_id with an attribute_name of sku and join against that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `view_test` 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT entity_id 
    FROM `view_test` 
    WHERE (attribute_name = 'sku') 
) bind
ON view_test.entity_id = bind.entity_id
```

Comment: The limit is necessary to paginate the result in blocks, your answer is correct. i miss find_in_set to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT t.*, group_concat(t2.id) FROM `test` t
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.attribute_name = 'sku' and t.id != t2.id
group by t.id;
```

row, and the list of all ids that have same SKU

Comment: Sorry no luck, i updated my question with more accurate data.

Comment: k, remove t.id != t2.id condition, and the output will be simialr to the output you posted, but there will be no "missed ids" :)